# Wordpress Add media show error message

Tags: wordpress

When I try upload file in "POSTS" or "PAGES" section click "Add media", when uploading get error: *"An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."*

If I uploading file in "Media" section I not getting this error.

I try:

- Disable all plugins
- Set folder permissions
- Reinstall wordpress

But still getting same error when uploading files not in "Media" section

Comment: Have you checked php error logs?

Comment: Not getting any errors.

Comment: No way. If you getting that error, there must be error on php error logi file, or in apache error log file. Double check it

Comment: I'm getting custom error not php error.

Comment: what filetype and what is the size ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the "wp-config.php" in your theme.
2) Then open it in editor.

3) Set Debugging false. If it is true. and save the file.
   define ('WP_DEBUG',false);

4) By doing so you would not be able to see errors in php files or pages on browser but you would able to upload files.

5) Set Debugging 'true' after uploading images or file. if you want to see error on your browser.

Hope it solves your problem.